# Unity 2D Physics Material 2D issue bounciness

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, pong

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a simple game: Pong.
I've used the physics material with 0 friction and 1 bounciness for the ball, so I don't have to make every collision by code. 
The problem is the following: if the ball has a low degree angle and hit the ground (or the ceiling), the ball will start move only horizontally and stop to bounce. Why dodes this happen?

Here is a little gif with the problem:

[image: Problem of the ball not bouncing correctly]

Thanks! Ask me anything if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [physics 2D settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) under `Edit` > `Project Settings` > `Physics2D`

[image]

Reduce the

> **Velocity Threshold**
>
> Set the threshold for elastic collisions
> . Unity treats collisions with a relative velocity lower than this value as inelastic collisions (that is, the colliding GameObjects **do not bounce** off each other).

If your angle is very flat the relative velocity for the collision impact is very small as well.